# LuaLaTeX: use or don't use classical font packages?

Tags: fonts, packages, luatex, latin-modern

In the lualatex-doc I am reading under "switching from LaTeX to LuaLaTeX":

1. Don’t load `inputenc`, just encode your source in UTF-8.
2. Don’t load `fontenc`, but load `fontspec`.
3. Don’t use any package that changes the fonts, but use `fontspec`’s commands instead.

Consider the following example:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
Hellöö! ßßäü
\end{document}
```

It compiles perfectly fine and looks as desired with lualatex from TeXLive 2012. It is in agreement with points (1) and (2) from the list above. However, I am wondering:

- Doesn't `\usepackage{lmodern}` violate point (3) from above?

If yes:

- What would be the LuaLaTeX way of using `lmodern`?
- Why does it work then? In which cases is this expected to break?

I just took `lmodern` as an example, the question applies to all such kinds of font packages.

Comment: `fontspec` uses Latin Modern by default (the OpenType version), but you can also load it manually like any other font: `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}` etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your example works as there exists suitable font definitions files for the "lmr" and the "lmss" families for the EU2 font encoding in the `euenc` package. (If you look in the log-file you will see that a `eu2lmss.fd` is loaded).

If you would replace `lmodern` by e.g. `times` it would no longer work. You would see in the log-file a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    No file EU2phv.fd. on input line 14.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/phv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU2/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 14.
```

And the document wouldn't use helvet but the fallback lmr.

To be able to use the helvet font you would have to switch the fontencoding to an encoding for which font definitions for helvet exists, e.g. T1-encoding. But with this encoding you will no longer be able to input non-ascii-chars directly:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{times}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
¼½¾ Hellöö! ßßäü
% this gives helvet, but some chars are wrong:
\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont ¼½¾ Hellöö! ßßäü \ss
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrike for these insights. So the take home message is that we really should use the fontspec commands indead of e.g. `\usepackage{times}`.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke The take home message is: It depends on the package. `lmodern` or e.g. `libertine` works fine with lualatex as they are adapted to EU2 encoding. Symbol fonts like e.g. wasysym or chessfonts works fine too, as their commands switch locally to suitable encodings. Some packages like times are ignored and so useless. And there are also packages which could mess up the font setup e.g. if they change to LGR or T2A encoding.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Are you sure about wasysym? When I replace `lmodern` with `wasysym` and add e.g. `\currency` to the document, I get a `!LuaTeX error (file wasy10): Font wasy10 at 657 not found`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dapperdan: You haven't enabled the map file correctly (updmap/updmap-sys depending on your system). You can add it locally to your document with `\pdfmapfile{=wasy.map}`.